# Cannot search for artifact in Eclipse Kepler using m2e plugin - "Gives Artifact id empty"

Tags: eclipse, maven-plugin, m2eclipse, eclipse-kepler

I recently installed maven plug-in in Eclipse Kepler.  But when I try to add a dependency (open the pom.xml, go to dependencies tab and click add) I can input some string like "spring" in the search box but nothing happens. Ideally a list of all dependencies containing "spring" should pop up.  But it shows: "Artifact Id cannot be empty".

I  have changed Windows- preference- Maven -“Download repository index updates on  startup” also I have changed the central repository to “Enable full Index” and did rebuild index. Still no luck

When i tried to add the dependency manually to the pom.xml and save it (in eclipse itself) the changes does not get saved.

I do not  have any network issues.

Please help me out here. It would be of great help .

Comment: You need to enable index on global repo. Look at Maven Repositories view.

Comment: Oh I already did that ! Still same results. Any idea of anything else that might help me resolve this? I have been trying to figure this out one whole day and still no luck.  Thanks Aleksandr.

Comment: I saw something similar to this recently and the comment seemed to mention that m2e and the Maven Eclipse plugin confuse each other if both are loaded in the same install...

Answer (score 0):

Try installing 'M2E Connector for the maven-dependency-plugin' from the Eclipse Marketplace under the Help tab.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.